# ExtJS Store proxy incorrectly build GET request with array in extraParams

Tags: php, extjs, get, extjs4

I want to pass additional filter data to my PHP REST service, namely a set of values from a form. Form is a set of checkboxes with a same `name: 'relations'`.

To do this, I do the following:

```
var relationTypes = [],
    objectsTreeStore = Ext.getCmp('objectsTreeGrid').getStore();
if( 'relations' in this.getFilterForm().getValues() ) {
    relationTypes = typeof this.getFilterForm().getValues().relations ==='string' ? [this.getFilterForm().getValues().relations] : this.getFilterForm().getValues().relations;
}
objectsTreeStore.getProxy().extraParams.relations = relationTypes;
objectsTreeStore.load();
```

As example, value of `relationTypes` variable according to `console.log` is `["100_200", "110_200"]`.

But GET request URL is `http://10.161.28.111:81/objectstree/get?branch_id=2&relations=100_200&relations=110_200&node=root`.

PHP interprent this data as

```
Array
(
    [branch_id] => 2
    [relations] => 110_200
    [node] => root
)
```

I think that URL should be like `http://10.161.28.111:81/objectstree/get?branch_id=2&relations[]=100_200&relations[]=110_200&node=root`.

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to name your checkboxes `name: 'relations[]'` ?

You can also use `CheckboxGroup` container for correct behaviour. Docs — http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.CheckboxGroup

Comment: I use `checkboxGroups` in my form. `name: 'relations[]'` worked, but it seems to me that this is a very tough solution, moreover, I do not understand how I can access this value if necessary. For example `this.getFilterForm().getValues().relations[]` wont work.

Comment: Yes, it's ugly. Anyway, `getValues` function returns an array, so, you can retrieve values like this `this.getFilterForm().getValues()['relations[]']`